How do I install shepherd.js locally?
Every time I try to install shepherd.js locally I get errors. I've completely deleted my node_modules folder, then run npm install successfully, but I get the following output from npm install shepherd.js --save:
% npm install shepherd.js --save
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
npm ERR! The "from" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/chuck/.npm/_logs/2024-04-25T22_44_44_340Z-debug-0.log
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
% npm install shepherd.js --save
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /Users/chuck/Projects/clients/project/node_modules/deepmerge
npm ERR! dest /Users/chuck/Projects/clients/project/node_modules/.deepmerge-JE81VUiY
npm ERR! errno -66
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/Users/chuck/Projects/clients/project/node_modules/deepmerge' -> '/Users/chuck/Projects/clients/project/node_modules/.deepmerge-JE81VUiY'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/chuck/.npm/_logs/2024-04-25T22_44_51_749Z-debug-0.log

Thinking maybe that last message is an instruction, I tried renaming the file, but the same last error happened.
Note that I am able to install the module globally. This is using nom 10.5.1, which I uninstalled and reinstalled (on macOS via brew).

Assuming this was you, opening this support ticket is the right way forward. It's unlikely something anyone here can help with

@Phil It was, ty, will delete this shortly (so you can see this grateful response :) ).

At least the Shepherd project looks actively maintained. You should get a response there
